# Simple solution for @"\b \b"

Tags: c#

I am trying read one string from TextBox and use in my script.
Suppose this TextBox name is: txt3.
I want read this value and use in below lines:

```
string s = Regex.Replace(str, 
                         @"\btxt3.Text\b", 
                         txt4.Text, 
                         RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

How I can write this `@"\btxt3.Text\b"` ?
I want write that as :
`string str==@"\btxt3.Text\b";`

Comment: Google string concatination and String.Format. your question has nothing to do with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
string s = Regex.Replace(str, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b",txt3.Text), txt4.Text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", txt3.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine value of txt3 with other strings, one way to do it is write

```
"\\b" + txt3.Text + "\\b"
```

instead of

```
@"\btxt3.Text\b"
```

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes (and fix your quotes).

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't it the case when using them for RegEx word selector to keep them as is - \bword\b ? Thanks for the quotes tho, fixed

Comment: Nope, if the regex is to match a word boundary, i.e. `\b`, it needs to be escaped in the string pattern. In the second example, the verbatim modifier (`@`) takes care of this but - in the absence of this - you need to escape the backslash so the string contains the literal "\b" instead of the escaped character '\b'.